# How to check that all predicates of a specified name have the specified number of arguments?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have many predicates used to hold data. I have manually entered all that data by hand. Now I need to ensure that all of them have the same number of arguments.

Take the example below, where I need to ensure that `data` always has 6 arguments:

```
% data(Id, Name, Age, Street, City, Phone).
data(1, 'John', 12, "1 New Street", "Central City", "873289712").
data(2, 'Ali', 11, "122 Sesame Street", "Central City", "823283821").
% ...
```

How can I write a predicate that checks whether or not all `data` predicates have the correct number of arguments? If the number of arguments is incorrect for a particular entry, I would like to know which entry is incorrect.

For example:

```
CheckArguments(data, 6).
```

Should give `false` if there exists a predicate `data(2, 'Farah').`, because this entry only has 2 arguments out of the required 6. In addition, the predicate should have some way of telling me that the offending predicate is `data(2, 'Farah').`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ISO Prolog standard predicate `current_predicate/1`. For example, after loading your data clauses:

```
| ?- current_predicate(data/Arity).
```

Backtrack into all solutions to get all the arities for user-defined predicates with name `data`.